# How can I properly format text quotes such that Gmail will render them graphically?

Tags: gmail, formatting

To see what I have in mind see following screenshots from my Gmail.
Whole thread is publicly accessible in [gmane](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.openjdk.core-libs.devel/21310/).

[image: nicely formatted quote]

His quoting format ([raw source](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.openjdk.core-libs.devel/21319/raw)):

```
On 9/21/2013 11:43 AM, Marcin Wi=C5=9Bnicki wrote:
> First of all EnumSet/EnumMap are not general purpose collections, they
> are already implementation specific.
>
> Also, since you can't subclass enum, class of contained values will be
> the same as declaring class.

No, not necessarily.
```

While my message is colored but not formatted graphically:

[image: quote not formatted]

Here is the source ([raw](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.openjdk.core-libs.devel/21320/raw)):

```
On Sat, Sep 21, 2013 at 10:21 PM, Remi Forax <forax@univ-mlv.fr> wrote:
> No, you can add methods to one value of an enum using the anonymous class
> syntax.
>
>

Thanks for pointing this out. This is something that can be clarified
in javadoc.
```

The only difference being format of date and presence of email. Both inserted by Gmail. I've tried correcting them both to look like the other message but with no success.